# Power Query remove rows that duplicate prior rows

Tags: powerquery

I know it's a recurrent question … but didn't find the solution in other posts

I’ve a consolidated database (consolidation of weekly reports) to track challenges on weekly basis.

Looks:

[image]

As you can see in this consolidated database, each action follow up is not done every week => meaning that field “Action” in my database remain the same until any update.

[image]

Would there be a way in Power Query to remove lines where:

`“Initiation Date”, “Initiator”, “Topic”, “Issue Description”, “Supplier”, “Product / SKU”, “Action”` are exactly the same as a older (based on “Report”) one

Thanks for your support.

Fab

I spend time on Google looking for tuto or similar requests

---

---

**Edit 11th of March**
Very strange wow where I must edit my initial message to continue the discussion.

**@horseyride**
Thank you very much spending time to look at my issue. And tks for the step-by-step approach. I'm not that I understood all (I'm quite novice with Power Bi).

**Step 1:** Creation of the concatenated column There, I'm not sure of the final goal: • Either getting all topics related to each subject ("Issue Description") => field "Action" not included (as it will evolve over time) • Or getting all topics with actions => with your formulae, I created 2 new columns: • "Concatenation" • "ConcatenationWithActions"

**Step 2:** Add column, index column I think I did it well
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USgFT.jpg)

**Step 3:** Add the Previous row formulae I'm not sure to understand the purpose as the line I + 1 is not related to line i
Should I first put a Sort Ascending?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5P4D.jpg)

In order to facilitate discussion, I created a 2 demo files

- Demo file.pbix with the database without any operations
- Demo file v2.pbix with the steps 1 to 3

Unfortunately, I don't have rights to attach file => I used WeTransfer. You can download them [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d3bf5844fc45320135246810a182a84c20230310171433/33053a9115c3db200dfd1c1324cbc7fb20230310171445/4e7f5a?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid)

Have a nice week-end

Fab

Comment: When asking questions, please post sample data as text not images. We don't want to retype all that

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way to do this

add column, custom column, that merges the columns you are interested in checking using column name **custom**

```
= Text.Combine({[b],[c],[d],[e]})
```

Add column, index column, with all the default options

add column, custom column, to pull in the value from the prior row into new column named **PrevRow**

```
= try #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Custom] otherwise null
```

add column, custom column, to check current row against previous row

```
= if Text.Combine({[b],[c],[d],[e]}) = [PrevRow] then "dupe" else "ok"
```

use drop down atop this last new column to filter and remove "dupe"

[image]

right click and remove the extra columns and you go from left to right

[image]

full sample code you could paste into home .. advanced editor ..

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Text.Combine({[b],[c],[d],[e]})),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
#"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "PrevRow", each try #"Added Index"{[Index]-1}[Custom] otherwise null),
#"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "check", each if Text.Combine({[b],[c],[d],[e]}) = [PrevRow] then "dupe" else "ok"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom2", each ([check] = "ok")),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Index", "PrevRow", "check", "Custom"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

if your rows are not in proper order, sort them as the first step

Comment: Hi@horseyride,I've not been able to complete your step by step methodology. As there is no layout possibility with this Comment box, I edited my message to clarify the difficulty I faced. Tks and very good week-end. Fab

Comment: I am unable to read pbx files due to corporate restrictions and don't understand the  difficulties you are having so perhaps someone else can assist you. Good luck